# Anonymous Struct Declaration

Tags: c#

Say I have the following declarations:

```
struct SomeStructure
{
    string Message;
    int StartValue;
    int EndValue;
}

SomeStructure _SomeStructure;
```

I will never have more than one `SomeStructure` variable declared so I was wondering if there's a way to combine the two together in a single statement, something like:

```
struct SomeStructure
{
    string Message;
    int StartValue;
    int EndValue;
} _SomeStructure;
```

I need to make it explicit that no other variables using the struct are to be declared.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: If I understand correctly the association of a `Message`, `StartValue` and `EndValue` is a one-shot object ? (=used once in one place)

Comment: @mjwills how about ValueTuple: `(string Message, int StartValue, int EndValue) _SomeStructure; `

Comment: Are you wanting this to be like a singleton? ie if something else tries to create it it returns the single already existing thing? Or do you want to limit it so that only one particular place in the code is able to create or retrieve this item?

Comment: @Magnus It is about the closest you will get, yes. Which is why I upvoted that option below.

Answer (score 4):

ValueTuple seems to be the perfect fit for your requirements:

- Make explicit this is a one-shot value
- Implemented behind the scene as a `struct`

`var _SomeStructure = (Message: "Hello", StartValue: 1, EndValue: 2);`

Or without using `var` (as requested):

`(string Message, int StartValue, int EndValue) _SomeStructure = ("Hello", 1, 2);`

Comment: `var` cannot be used at the module level, hence my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create anonymous entities like this.

```
var v = new { Message = "Hello" , StartValue = 1, EndValue = 2};
```

For more details, look at the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

However, for strict typing, you will need to create a `struct` or `class`.

Comment: IIRC, anonymous types are implemented as classes, not structs

Comment: You are correct, but in practice the anonymous types are so limited, it makes little difference.

Comment: It depends on the use case really... if memory location (`stack` vs `heap`) or type (`value` vs `reference`) are important, it could make quite a large difference. Of course, if neither of those are factors are relevant, anonymous types are fine.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question.
I need to make it explicit that no other variables using the struct are to be declared.
I modified the question to make it clear.